# Bootstrap-4 spacing class mb-2 doesn't work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

The Bootstrap-4 spacing class mb-2 doesn't work while ml-2 does work. Here's the code,

```
.mb-2 { 
   margin-bottom: 1.5rem !important;
  }
```

!important should override other margin-bottom definitions. Also what does the 1.5rem reference, that is how many pixels?

Comment: There is no fixed *rem* to *px* conversion, because *rem* is based on your `html` tags font-size. If your `html` has `font-size: 16px;` each element with `font-size: 1.0rem;` has a `font-size` of 16px. With regard to your real problem it would be helpful if you post some more code or a jsfiddle so we can see better where's a mistake

Comment: Please post a **minimal working example** of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a [Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: bootstrap html font-size is undeclared, I guess the browser decide default font-size

Comment: Seems to work fine: http://www.codeply.com/go/uuDtGDS3Hb Post your code.